# DynamoDB table not created in serverless.yml file

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

Getting the error `cannot do operation on a non-existent table` after running `sls offline start` and attempting to access the users endpoint. serverless.yml file is as follows:

```
service: 
  name: digital-secret

plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-offline # must be last in the list

custom:
  userTableName: 'users-table-${self:provider.stage}'
  dynamoDb:
    start:
      migrate: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - 'dynamodb:Query'
        - 'dynamodb:Scan'
        - 'dynamodb:GetItem'
        - 'dynamodb:PutItem'
        - 'dynamodb:UpdateItem'
        - 'dynamodb:DeleteItem'
      Resource:
        - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["usersTable", "Arn"] }
  environment:
    USERS_TABLE: ${self:custom.userTableName}

functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
  user:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: 'GET /users/{proxy+}'
      - http: 'POST /users'

resources:
  Resources:
    usersTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.userTableName}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Can anyone help point out what is wrong here? I've looked through the docs and at many different examples available online, but nothing I can see is different than the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`serverless-dynamodb-local`](https://github.com/99xt/serverless-dynamodb-local) docs say that the `custom` block should be structured like this:

```
custom:
  dynamodb:
    start:
      migrate: true
```

You have `dynamoDb` instead of `dynamodb`

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is having issues with this, I spent hours trying to track down this issue and it was because I inadvertently had the wrong case for the [r]esources section in serverless.yml

```
Resources:    <-- Needs to be lower case 'r'
  Resources:
    usersTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
  ...
```